# hazelcast ScheduledExecutorService lost tasks after node shutdown

Tags: hazelcast

I'm trying to use hazelcast ScheduledExecutorService to execute some periodic tasks. I'm using hazelcast 3.8.1.

I start one node and then the other, and the tasks are distributed between both nodes and properly executed.

If I shutdown the first node, then the second one will start to execute the periodic tasks that were previously on the first node.

The problem is that, if I stop the second node instead of the first, then its tasks are not rescheduled to the first one. This happens even if I have more nodes. If I shutdown the last node to receive tasks, those tasks are lost.

The shutdown is always done with ctrl+c

I've created a test application, with some sample code from hazelcast examples and with some pieces of code I've found on the web. I start two instances of this app.

```
public class MasterMember {

/**
 * The constant LOG.
 */
final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MasterMember.class);

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Config config = new Config();
    config.setProperty("hazelcast.logging.type", "slf4j");
    config.getScheduledExecutorConfig("scheduler").
    setPoolSize(16).setCapacity(100).setDurability(1);

    final HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {

        HazelcastInstance threadInstance = instance;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            logger.info("Application shutdown");

            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                logger.info("Verifying whether it is safe to close this instance");
                boolean isSafe = getResultsForAllInstances(hzi -> {
                    if (hzi.getLifecycleService().isRunning()) {
                        return hzi.getPartitionService().forceLocalMemberToBeSafe(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    }
                    return true;
                });

                if (isSafe) {
                    logger.info("Verifying whether cluster is safe.");
                    isSafe = getResultsForAllInstances(hzi -> {
                        if (hzi.getLifecycleService().isRunning()) {
                            return hzi.getPartitionService().isClusterSafe();
                        }
                        return true;
                    });

                    if (isSafe) {
                        System.out.println("is safe.");
                        break;
                    }
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            threadInstance.shutdown();

        }

        private boolean getResultsForAllInstances(
                Function<HazelcastInstance, Boolean> hazelcastInstanceBooleanFunction) {

            return Hazelcast.getAllHazelcastInstances().stream().map(hazelcastInstanceBooleanFunction).reduce(true,
                    (old, next) -> old && next);
        }
    });

    new Thread(() -> {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        IScheduledExecutorService scheduler = instance.getScheduledExecutorService("scheduler");
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(named("1", new EchoTask("1")), 5, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(named("2", new EchoTask("2")), 5, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(named("3", new EchoTask("3")), 5, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(named("4", new EchoTask("4")), 5, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(named("5", new EchoTask("5")), 5, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(named("6", new EchoTask("6")), 5, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }).start();

    new Thread(() -> {

        try {
            // delays init
            Thread.sleep(20000);

            while (true) {

                IScheduledExecutorService scheduler = instance.getScheduledExecutorService("scheduler");
                final Map<Member, List<IScheduledFuture<Object>>> allScheduledFutures =
                        scheduler.getAllScheduledFutures();

                // check if the subscription already exists as a task, if so, stop it
                for (final List<IScheduledFuture<Object>> entry : allScheduledFutures.values()) {
                    for (final IScheduledFuture<Object> objectIScheduledFuture : entry) {
                        logger.info(
                                "TaskStats: name {} isDone() {} isCanceled() {} total runs {} delay (sec) {} other statistics {} ",
                                objectIScheduledFuture.getHandler().getTaskName(), objectIScheduledFuture.isDone(),
                                objectIScheduledFuture.isCancelled(),
                                objectIScheduledFuture.getStats().getTotalRuns(),
                                objectIScheduledFuture.getDelay(TimeUnit.SECONDS),
                                objectIScheduledFuture.getStats());
                    }
                }

                Thread.sleep(15000);

            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }).start();

    while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    // Hazelcast.shutdownAll();
}
}
```

And the task

```
public class EchoTask implements Runnable, Serializable {

/**
 * serialVersionUID
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5505122140975508363L;

final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EchoTask.class);

private final String msg;

public EchoTask(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    logger.info("--> " + msg);
}
}
```

I'm I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

---

-- EDIT --

Modified (and updated above) the code to use log instead of system.out. Added logging of task statistics and fixed usage of the Config object.

The logs:

[Node1_log](https://pastebin.com/xUxzxxZD)

[Node2_log](https://pastebin.com/Da2AjUXe)

Forgot to mention that I wait until all the task are running in the first node before starting the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bruno, thanks for reporting this, and it really is a bug. Unfortunately it was not so obvious with multiple nodes as it is with just two. As you figured by your answer its not losing the task, but rather keep it cancelled after a migration. Your fix, however is not safe because a Task can be cancelled and have null Future at the same time, eg. when you cancel the master replica, the backup which never had a future, just gets the result. The fix is very close to what you did, so in the `prepareForReplication()` when in `migrationMode` we avoid setting the result. I will push a fix for that shortly, just running a few more tests. This will be available in master and later versions.

I logged an issue with your finding, if you don't mind, https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/10603 you can keep track of its status there.

Comment: Thank you. Will this fix be available just when 3.9 comes out? Is there a estimate date for the release?

Comment: Will back-port this to 3.8.3, but don't have dates for either of the releases. They are both expected very soon.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do a quick fix for this issue by changing the ScheduledExecutorContainer class of the hazelcast project (used 3.8.1 source code), namely the promoteStash() method. Basically I've added a condition for the case were we task was cancelled on a previous migration of data. 
I don't now the possible side effects of this change, or if this is the best way to do it!

```
 void promoteStash() {
    for (ScheduledTaskDescriptor descriptor : tasks.values()) {
        try {
            if (logger.isFinestEnabled()) {
                logger.finest("[Partition: " + partitionId + "] " + "Attempt to promote stashed " + descriptor);
            }

            if (descriptor.shouldSchedule()) {
                doSchedule(descriptor);
            } else if (descriptor.getTaskResult() != null && descriptor.getTaskResult().isCancelled()
                    && descriptor.getScheduledFuture() == null) {
                // tasks that were already present in this node, once they get sent back to this node, since they
                // have been cancelled when migrating the task to other node, are not rescheduled...
                logger.fine("[Partition: " + partitionId + "] " + "Attempt to promote stashed canceled task "
                        + descriptor);

                descriptor.setTaskResult(null);
                doSchedule(descriptor);
            }

            descriptor.setTaskOwner(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw rethrow(e);
        }
    }
}
```