# Hazelcast ScheduledExecutor Task Queue is filling up

Tags: hazelcast

I'm submitting tasks to a Hazelcast `IScheduledExecutorService` (Hazelcast 3.12.4)

```
hazelcast.getScheduledExecutorService(DELAYED_EVENT_EXECUTOR_SERVICE_NAME).schedule(task, delay, units);
```

This has been working fine, now suddenly I am getting errors

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Maximum capacity (200) of tasks reached, for scheduled executor (delayedEventExecutor). Reminder that tasks must be disposed if not needed.
        at com.hazelcast.scheduledexecutor.impl.ScheduledExecutorContainer.checkNotAtCapacity(ScheduledExecutorContainer.java:337)
        at com.hazelcast.scheduledexecutor.impl.ScheduledExecutorContainer.schedule(ScheduledExecutorContainer.java:92)
        at 

com.hazelcast.scheduledexecutor.impl.operations.ScheduleTaskOperation.run(ScheduleTaskOperation.java:45)
```

Other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982253/hazelcast-scheduledexecutorservice-lost-tasks-after-node-shutdown) seem to indicate that we need to call `future.dispose()` on the returned future. But the task executes in the future (that's kind of the point) - are we required to hold onto all the futures in some kind of list and `dispose()` them after they have executed?  That seems crazy. I suppose we could give the task a reference to the `Future`, and then at the end of the `run()` method call `dispose()`, but that seems silly (not to mention that the executor service is distributed and the task might need to be serialized and moved to another node).

How can we call `dispose()` on the `Future`s of tasks that execute hours in the future?  Or is there some other way to stop this error message?

Answer (score 1):

`IScheduledExecutorService` creates and executes a one-shot action that becomes enabled after the given delay.
It has two configuration attributes related to your question:

- `pool-size`: Number of executor threads per member for the executor.
- `capacity`: Maximum number of tasks that a scheduler can have per partition.
  Tasks should get disposed by the user with calling `future.dispose()` to free up the capacity.

You can find the documentation here: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#scheduled-executor-service

Keeping `IScheduledFuture` objects in a list and dispose them later will only occupy the capacity. Instead, you can call `future.get()` to get the result and dispose it right after the execution and keep the results in a list if you need.

For illustration:

```
ArrayList resultList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
IScheduledExecutorService executorService = member.getScheduledExecutorService("myScheduler");
IScheduledFuture<Integer> future = executorService.schedule(
                new SampleTask(), 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

int result= future.get(); // Block until we get the result
resultList.add(result);
future.dispose(); // Always dispose futures that are not in use any more, to release resources
```

Futures associated with a scheduled task are always strongly referenced, in order to be aware of lost partitions and/or members, act as listeners on the local member/client. 
Upon partition specific scheduling, the future task is stored both in the primary partition and also in its N backups. If a Hazelcast member lost, the task is re-scheduled on the backup.
Upon member specific scheduling, the future task is only stored in the member itself, which means that in the event of a lost member, the task is lost as well.

If you don't want to block with `future.get()` till you get the result, consider having a look at `ICompletableFuture`

Comment: I don't want to block until I get the result - if I wanted that, I wouldn't need a ScheduledExecutor, I'd just run the task synchonously. Also, what if I'm scheduling the task for execution in 3 hours - do I block the thread for 3 hours?  My server would crash. Also, the tasks are serializable and might actually execute on a different node.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of code will not work for me:

```
IScheduledExecutorService executorService = member.getScheduledExecutorService("myScheduler");
IScheduledFuture<Integer> future = executorService.schedule(
                new SampleTask(), 3, TimeUnit.HOURS);

int result = future.get(); // Block the calling thread for 3 hours and crash the server
future.dispose();
```

So my solution was to build a database-based delayed executor.  I store the Spring Bean name, the method name, and the serialized parameters in the database, along with a delivery timestamp. The ugly part is that I have to poll the database periodically to look for events that need delivery. If their time has arrived, I use an `applicationContext.getBean()` call to find the instance, deserialize the parameters and use reflection to invoke the `Method`. Upon success, I remove the database data.